# grep a file using results from awk as parameter?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, hashtable, cat

I have 2 files:

1 - userfile.txt with format=>    bob:bobhash
2 - passfile.txt with format=>    bobhash:bobpass

I want to get the bobpass by given the user "bob", in a single line command if possible.

So, far i'm doing it like this:

```
awk -F: '$1="bob" {print $2}' userfile.txt
# output: bobhash 
# copy by using mouse

cat passfile.txt | grep 'bobhash' | awk -F: '{print $2}'
#output: bobpass
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. I already tried `grep -f`, but no luck.

Comment: Yes just use one awk command instead of multiple awks+grep. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and you'll get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following *one-line* `awk` approach:

```
awk -F: 'NR == FNR{ if($1=="bob") p=$2; next}(p == $1){print $2}' userfile.txt passfile.txt
```

Here we have processing of two files.
How it works:

> $ awk 'NR == FNR { # some actions; next} # other condition {# other
>   actions}' file1.txt file2.txt
>
> When processing more than one file, **awk** reads each file sequentially,
>   one after another, in the order they are specified on the command
>   line. The special variable **NR** stores the total number of input records
>   read so far, regardless of how many files have been read. The value of
>   **NR** starts at 1 and always increases until the program terminates.
>   Another variable, **FNR**, stores the number of records read *from the
>   current file being processed*. The value of **FNR** starts at 1, increases
>   until the end of the current file is reached, then is set again to 1
>   as soon as the first line of the next file is read, and so on. So, the
>   condition **NR == FNR** is only *true while awk is reading the first file*.
>   Thus, in the program above, the actions indicated by **# some actions**
>   are executed when awk is reading the first file; the actions indicated
>   by **# other actions** are executed when awk is reading the second file,
>   if the condition in **# other condition** is met. The **next** at the end of
>   the first action block is needed to prevent the condition in **# other
>   condition** from being evaluated, and the actions in **# other actions**
>   from being executed, while awk is reading the first file.

Comment: I guess that with the same way you can open '1 to n' files and manipulate their output. This is a complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: Another thing, can i pass variables and print them from the first file to the other? For example `awk -F:' #code....{print p:$2}' file1 file2` . So, i could have the output `bob:bobpass`

Comment: @ioaniatr, welcome, you can pass a variable via `-v` option(assigns a value to a variable) like `awk -v name=bob '{print name;}'`. Also, you are able to initialize inner variables, for ex.: `awk 'BEGIN { ret = getline < "junk.txt"; if (ret == -1) print "Error:", ERRNO }'`

Comment: Works fine. Just a notice is better to use syntax `awk -v name='bob' ...#code` in case that the vars_value has special characters like `name='B@$/b'`

Comment: @ioaniatr right, in shell you should always use single quotes by default until you have a specific need to use double quotes (e.g. to expand a variable) and then use double quotes until you have a specific need to use no quotes (e.g. for globbing and filename expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Run `awk` once :

```
awk -v search=bob -F: 'NR==FNR && $1==search {hash=$2 };
    NR>FNR && $1==hash {print "pw=" $2 }'  userfile.txt passfile.txt
```

You can change this for some control when a match is not found (or twice).

Answer (score 0):

In case that it is of some interest, this is a global solution that will match all users in userfile.txt with their corresponding passwords in passfile.txt

```
awk -F":" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}a[$1]{print a[$1],$2}' users pass
```

Comment: Very usefull in case that i wanted to get all the users from the "usersfile.txt" and maybe store them in a new file by adding at the end `> newfile.txt `.

Comment: @ioaniatr Yes, this is exactly what i thought. You can print them on the screen or send them to a new file. As a "bad usage" you could print all users/passwords and grep for Bob :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a modified version of what you already have that may get you what you're after.

Simple one liner:

```
cat passfile.txt | grep "$(awk -v user="bob" -F: '$1=user {print $2}' userfile.txt)" | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

Modified for use in a script:

```
my_user="bob"

cat passfile.txt | grep "$(awk -v user="${my_user}" -F: '$1=user {print $2}' userfile.txt)" | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

The second option adds the ability to pass in a user as a variable as opposed to hard coding it. If you're using this in a script it can be set dynamically making this more flexible.

Another solution using awk only:

```
awk -F: -v user="$(awk -F: '$1="bob" {print $2}' userfile.txt)" '$1=user {print $2}' passfile.txt
```

Comment: UUOC and you never need grep when you're using awk since awk can do everything uesful that grep can do.

Comment: Fair statement. I suppose I always try to approach these questions by making the smallest impact on their code to get the results they want. Sometimes it's easier for people to understand things that way. However, I've edited my answer to also show how this is done without grep, because you are right, it isn't necessary.